# Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql, class-validator

```
import { isEmail, isEmpty, isPhoneNumber, Length } from "class-validator"
import { Field, InputType } from "type-graphql";

@InputType()
export class RegisterInput {
    @Field()
    @Length(2, 15, { message: "Username Must Be At Least 2 characters" })
    username?: string;

    @Field()
    @isEmail()
    email?: string;

    @Field()
    @Length(1, 20)
    @isPhoneNumber()
    phoneNumber?: string;

    @isEmpty()
    password?: string

}
```

The thing is @isEmail() and @isPhoneNumber() and @isEmpty() throw the same error:

```
Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  This expression is not callable.
    Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.ts(1240)
```

Please help me out I've been stuck with this bug the whole day

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to write those Decorators with a capital letter. TypeScript is case sensitive:

```
import { IsEmail, IsEmpty, IsPhoneNumber, Length } from "class-validator";

@Field()
@IsEmail()
email?: string;

@Field()
@Length(1, 20)
@IsPhoneNumber()
phoneNumber?: string;

@IsEmpty()
password?: string
```

Comment: oh god, i feel so dumb. Thank you though !

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know anyone who did not run in such self made problems.  You're welcome. 

Answer (score 21):

You might need to add this property to your `tsconfig.json` file, under the `compilerOptions` property:

```
"experimentalDecorators": true
```

Kudos to Technical Rajni for the youtube video solution, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ90iW6kP_8).

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: This worked for ```@Entity()``` decorator too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For people who come here by googling the error message.

I had this error because I was importing the decorator from a `.js` file. Converting it to TypeScript resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I accidentally added a `;` after the decorator:

```
@minimumValue("quantity", 5);
async getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
...
```

This results in `TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.`.

So the correct syntax is without the `;`:

```
@minimumValue("quantity", 5)
async getItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use the property to your tsconfig.json file, under the compilerOptions property as mentioned above.

```json
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true
```

**Once you add this, make sure you delete the node_modules and reinstall it again.** Then it will work as expected. Avoid spelling errors.

Answer (score -2):

your problem is because you tried to invoke the class decorator by adding `()` at the end of it (`@InputType()`)

instead you should just do `@InputType`